# Sending a HTML Email using Send an Email from Shared Mailbox (V2) on Logic Apps

Tags: html, azure-logic-apps

I'm a beginner user of Azure and Logic Apps and Stack overflow and I'm trying to send a customised email using Logic Apps on Microsoft Azure.

I'm using the following guide (see below) to set my template onto a Logic App flow but I am facing issues with setting the HTML variable. When I set the variable as a HTML source code, the flow is unable to set the variable and and I do not receive an email.

The HTML Code I have used is just the source code from an email that I have sent to myself.

Is there something I have overlooked?
I noticed that for simple html changes (i.e. just bolding a sentence) the flow was able to work fine and I was able to receive an email.

Guide: https://blog.sandro-pereira.com/2020/01/26/logic-apps-how-to-send-a-well-formatted-html-email-notification-with-office-365-outlook-connector/

Example HTML Code:

````
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=us-ascii"><meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)"><style><!--
/* Font Definitions */
@font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
/* Style Definitions */
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0cm;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
    mso-fareast-language:EN-US;}
span.EmailStyle17
    {mso-style-type:personal-compose;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
    color:windowtext;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
    mso-fareast-language:EN-US;}
@page WordSection1
    {size:612.0pt 792.0pt;
    margin:72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" />
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
<o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" />
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]--></head><body lang=EN-AU link="#0563C1" vlink="#954F72" style='word-wrap:break-word'><div class=WordSection1><p class=MsoNormal>TestTESt<o:p></o:p></p></div></body></html> ```
````

Answer (score 1):

I followed the same instructions and noticed that the primary problem is in the code (i.e., most of the lines are commented), however when I attempted the same kind of approach with different HTML source code, it functioned perfectly though I was able to receive emails with the CSS styles that I applied.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about.

```html
html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta  http-equiv="Content-Type"  content="text/html; charset=utf-8"  />
<title>Internal CSS</title>
<style>
body{
background-color:#9F6;
}

h1{
color:#C39;
text-align:left;
text-transform:capitalize;
text-decoration:underline;
}

P{
font-size:20px;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
background-color:#FFF;
color:#963;
}

h2{
color:#F03;
margin-left:10px;
}

a{
margin-left:10px;
}
a:hover{ /*---------------This is formate of Pseudo-element---------------*/
color:#009;
font-size:18px;
font-weight:700;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Example for Internal CSS</h1>
<p>Cascading Style Sheet is a style language that defines layout of HTML documents.CSS properties such as background, border, font, float, display, margin, opacity, padding, text-align, vertical-align, position, color etc.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the screenshot of my received mail
[image]

Modifying the HTML code just within your variable and trying again should probably resolve the issue.

**REFERENCES:**

https://www.programming9.com/programs/html-codes/291-internal-style-sheet-with-an-example

Comment: Thanks for that info. I realised what my problem was haha

Answer (score 0):

I realised what the problem was on my end.
I didn't realise that there was a character limit for variables.

Changing the Logic App from a Stateless to Stateful Workflow fixed the issue.

More Info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config?tabs=azure-portal

[Character Limit Table For Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeGDz.png)